# Why are funds' transaction costs 1% of their portfolio turnover?

Tags: stocks, investing, mutual-funds, trading, index-fund

John Bogle suggests the transaction costs incurred by funds (and thus the lag they have on their investments) should be considered as 1% of the fund's portfolio turnover (0.5% for buy, and 0.5% for sell).

What's the theory behind this? And how is the cost relative, when typically transaction costs are defined as fixed amounts?

---

> The portfolio turnover costs of individual funds also tend to persist.
>   Transactions cost money, and we estimate that turnover costs are
>   roughly 0.5 percent on each purchase and sale, meaning that a fund
>   with 100 percent portfolio turnover would carry a cost to shareholders
>   of about 1 percent of assets, year after year. Similarly, 50 percent
>   turnover would cost about 0.50 percent; and 10 percent turnover would
>   cost about 0.10 percent, and so on. Rule of thumb: turnover costs
>   equal 1 percent of the turnover rate.
>
> -- John Bogle, 2007, The Little Book of Common Sense Investing

Comment: can you cite your source for this quote?

Comment: added the citation :)

Comment: Presumably the reason the cost is relative is that funds with a higher turnover are likely to engage in more transactions, not just larger transactions.  Transactions costs are fixed per transaction, but you still pay more if you do more transactions.

Comment: Well, that's why index funds -- with very little turnover -- have low operating costs and hence tend to do better than many (most?) of the actively-managed funds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclosure - I love Jack Bogle. Jack basically invented the index fund, and as a result, let the common investor have an opportunity to choose a long term return of (S&P-.05%) instead of losing nearly 2% that many funds in that day charged. The use of index investing has saved investors many billions of dollars.

The 1% round trip, total cost to buy/sell, was common. Fees for trading have since dropped. I happen to use Schwab who charges $9 for a trade. On $100,000, this is not .5% ($500) but less than .01%. I think it's safe to say that billion dollar mutual funds are paying even less for trades that I do. I believe Jack's example here is a combination of old data and hyperbole.

The cost is not so much for the trades, per se, but for the people managing the fund. An index fund has a manager of course, but it's pretty much run by a computer.

Comment: The commissions and the staff cost are already included in the reported expenses of the fund.  The hidden cost to trading that Bogle is talking about is the bid-ask spread, and propensity for a large fund to move the market against itself when it tries to trade.  (The reported values of bid-ask spread are generally narrower than 0.5%, but the theory is the reported value is largely fictitious due to HFT shenanigans.)